# Using HDMI input port

Tags: 15.10, hdmi, input

I have a dell inspiron aio running ubuntu 15.10 and it has a hdmi input port. I was planning to connect my chromecast to it (via hdmi) then casting my phone's screen to it or to just connect a set top box and watch tv on the aio. But connecting either of them on the pc doesnt help, nothing happens. I have tried rebooting and vlc too.